# How to change text color of ViewGroup's children

Tags: android, xml, layout, styles, viewgroup

Can I change the text color of ViewGroup's children instead of changing it on every child?

Like in CSS when I change the color in a div to red, all its children's color change to red.

Comment: Of course you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you apply theme on your activities, you may apply a custom theme to views from your xml layouts

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">

</RelativeLayout>
```